# Confluence Macro with external database driver

Tags: confluence

I am kind of frustrated with confluence again. I am trying to develop a simple macro with a database connection to an external database.

The problem is the database driver.

The plugin can not find the driver class in its classpath. Therefor I put the driver in the pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.1208.jre7</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I tried **compile** and **provided** for the scope.

I also read something about adding the packages to the configuration element of the pom.xml like this:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-confluence-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${amps.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <productVersion>${confluence.version}</productVersion>
                <productDataVersion>${confluence.data.version}</productDataVersion>
                <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>

                <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                <instructions>
                    <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>

                    <!-- Add package to export here -->
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.api,
                    </Export-Package>

                    <!-- Add package import here -->
                    <Import-Package>
                       org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                       org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
                        org.postgresql.*;resolution:="optional",
                        *
                    </Import-Package>

                    <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                    <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But this isn't changing anything. I will always get this error:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:16,931 WARN [ThreadPoolAsyncTaskExecutor::Thread 27] [labs.plugins.quickreload.spring] afterPropertiesSet
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Spring context started for bundle : com.atlassian.labs.plugins.quickreload id(215) v(1.24.1) reference:file:/C:/atlassian/tutorial-confluence-macro-demo/target/container/tomcat8x/cargo-confluence-home/webapps/confluence/WEB-INF/atlassian-bundled-plugins/quickreload-1.24.1.jar
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] If you want to debug the Spring wiring of your code then set a DEBUG level log level as follows.  [ This is a dev.mode only message. ]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   log4j.logger.com.atlassian.labs.plugins.quickreload.spring  = DEBUG, console, filelog
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:17,617 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin] enableInternal Detected an error (BundleException) enabling the plugin 'com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.tutorial-confluence-macro-demo-tests' : Unresolved constraint in bundle com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.tutorial-confluence-macro-demo-tests [238]: Unable to resolve 238.0: missing requirement [238.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.api) [caused by: Unable to resolve 149.0: missing requirement [149.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jna)].  This error usually occurs when your plugin imports a package from another bundle with a specific version constraint and either the bundle providing that package doesn't meet those version constraints, or there is no bundle available that provides the specified package. For more details on how to fix this, see https://developer.atlassian.com/x/mQAN
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:17,617 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [atlassian.plugin.impl.AbstractPlugin] enable Unable to enable plugin 'com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.tutorial-confluence-macro-demo-tests'
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:17,617 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [atlassian.plugin.impl.AbstractPlugin] enable Because of this exception
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.OsgiContainerException: Cannot start plugin: com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.tutorial-confluence-macro-demo-tests
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin.enableInternal(OsgiPlugin.java:407)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.impl.AbstractPlugin.enable(AbstractPlugin.java:286)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.PluginEnabler.actualEnable(PluginEnabler.java:130)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.PluginEnabler.enable(PluginEnabler.java:107)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager.enableDependentPlugins(DefaultPluginManager.java:1079)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugins(DefaultPluginManager.java:1055)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager.lateStartup(DefaultPluginManager.java:536)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.ConfluencePluginManager.lateStartup(ConfluencePluginManager.java:137)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.PluginFrameworkContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginFrameworkContextListener.java:79)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1704)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.tutorial-confluence-macro-demo-tests [238]: Unable to resolve 238.0: missing requirement [238.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.api) [caused by: Unable to resolve 149.0: missing requirement [149.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jna)]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin.enableInternal(OsgiPlugin.java:388)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 21 more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:17,618 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [atlassian.plugin.manager.PluginEnabler] actualEnable Unable to enable plugin com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.tutorial-confluence-macro-demo-tests
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.container.OsgiContainerException: Cannot start plugin: com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.tutorial-confluence-macro-demo-tests
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin.enableInternal(OsgiPlugin.java:407)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.impl.AbstractPlugin.enable(AbstractPlugin.java:286)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.PluginEnabler.actualEnable(PluginEnabler.java:130)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.PluginEnabler.enable(PluginEnabler.java:107)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager.enableDependentPlugins(DefaultPluginManager.java:1079)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugins(DefaultPluginManager.java:1055)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager.lateStartup(DefaultPluginManager.java:536)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.ConfluencePluginManager.lateStartup(ConfluencePluginManager.java:137)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.PluginFrameworkContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginFrameworkContextListener.java:79)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1704)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.tutorial-confluence-macro-demo-tests [238]: Unable to resolve 238.0: missing requirement [238.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.api) [caused by: Unable to resolve 149.0: missing requirement [149.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jna)]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin.enableInternal(OsgiPlugin.java:388)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 21 more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:17,985 INFO [ThreadPoolAsyncTaskExecutor::Thread 27] [plugins.quickreload.config.AutoRefresher] startupMessage
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  Quick Reload - ←[34mStealing back time from Maven since 2013.←[39m
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   Tracking the following directories for changes :
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           ←[33mC:\atlassian\tutorial-confluence-macro-demo\target←[39m
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ←[33m
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   The system property 'plugin.resource.directories' is as follows :
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           ←[33mC:\atlassian\tutorial-confluence-macro-demo\src\main\resources←[39m
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           ←[33mC:\atlassian\tutorial-confluence-macro-demo\src\test\resources←[39m
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ←[39m
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   The Control Panel page is available at :
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           ←[33m/plugins/servlet/qr←[39m
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   The REST API is available at :
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]           ←[33m/rest/qr/1.0/api←[39m
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   Web Resource batching and caching is currently ←[32menabled←[39m
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:28,931 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [confluence.plugin.dev.DeprecatedPluginModuleListener] findAndLogDeprecations Class com.atlassian.applinks.api.auth.types.TrustedAppsAuthenticationProvider of module 'com.atlassian.applinks.applinks-trustedapps-plugin:confluence-inbound-trusted' is deprecated
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:30,140 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [confluence.plugin.dev.DeprecatedPluginModuleListener] findAndLogDeprecations Class com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.dailysummary.analytics.SummaryEmailTrackingServlet of module 'com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.confluence-daily-summary-email:summaryEmailTrackingServlet' is deprecated
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:30,961 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [confluence.plugin.dev.DeprecatedPluginModuleListener] findAndLogDeprecations Class com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.like.notifications.NotificationListener of module 'com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.confluence-like:notificationListener' is deprecated
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,398 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [confluence.plugin.dev.DeprecatedPluginModuleListener] findAndLogDeprecations Type com.atlassian.plugin.webresource.transformer.WebResourceTransformer inherited by class com.atlassian.upm.template.UnderscoreTemplateWebResourceTransformer of module 'com.atlassian.upm.atlassian-universal-plugin-manager-plugin:javascriptTemplateWebResourceTransformer' is deprecated
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,399 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [confluence.plugin.dev.DeprecatedPluginModuleListener] findAndLogDeprecations Type com.atlassian.plugin.webresource.transformer.WebResourceTransformer inherited by class com.atlassian.upm.notification.NotificationWebResourceTransformer of module 'com.atlassian.upm.atlassian-universal-plugin-manager-plugin:notificationWebResourceTransformer' is deprecated
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,525 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [atlassian.confluence.cache.TransactionalCacheFactory] logNonTxUsageWarning Update operation performed on transactional cache [com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.CachingPluginStateStore] outside of a transaction. All updates to this cache should be performed from a thread with a valid transaction context.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,525 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] [atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager] lateStartup Plugin system lateStartup finished in 0:00:20.430
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,565 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.DefaultPluginUpgradeManager] upgradeInternal Running plugin upgrade tasks...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,571 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] doUpgrade Upgrading plugin com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-whitelist-core-plugin
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,575 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] upgradeTaskSucceeded Upgraded plugin com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-whitelist-core-plugin to version 1 - Migrate existing application links to the whitelist.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,578 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] upgradeTaskSucceeded Upgraded plugin com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-whitelist-core-plugin to version 2 - Migrate existing whitelist entries used by the RSS and HTML include macro.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,580 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] upgradeTaskSucceeded Upgraded plugin com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-whitelist-core-plugin to version 3 - Migrate existing Confluence Gadget whitelist data.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,580 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] postUpgrade Plugin com.atlassian.plugins.atlassian-whitelist-core-plugin upgrade completed. Current version is: 3
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:31,589 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] doUpgrade Upgrading plugin com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.confluence-roadmap-plugin
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:32,082 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] upgradeTaskSucceeded Upgraded plugin com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.confluence-roadmap-plugin to version 6 - Remove the "currentspaces" parameter from Roadmap macros
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:32,083 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] postUpgrade Plugin com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.confluence-roadmap-plugin upgrade completed. Current version is: 6
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:32,085 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] doUpgrade Upgrading plugin com.atlassian.upm.atlassian-universal-plugin-manager-plugin
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:32,123 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] upgradeTaskSucceeded Upgraded plugin com.atlassian.upm.atlassian-universal-plugin-manager-plugin to version 5 - Posts an initial topology report for a new UPM instance.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:32,123 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] postUpgrade Plugin com.atlassian.upm.atlassian-universal-plugin-manager-plugin upgrade completed. Current version is: 5
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:32,125 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] doUpgrade Upgrading plugin com.atlassian.support.stp
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:32,136 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] upgradeTaskSucceeded Upgraded plugin com.atlassian.support.stp to version 1 - Verify if the obsolete Health Check scheduler exists and remove it.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:32,136 INFO [lifecycle:thread-1] [sal.core.upgrade.PluginUpgrader] postUpgrade Plugin com.atlassian.support.stp upgrade completed. Current version is: 1
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:32,140 INFO [lifecycle:thread-5] [gadgets.renderer.internal.BlobCrypterImpl] onLifecycleEvent onLifecycleEvent LIFECYCLE_AWARE_ON_START
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:32,140 INFO [lifecycle:thread-5] [gadgets.renderer.internal.BlobCrypterImpl] onLifecycleEvent Startup lifecycle complete, initialising BlobCrypter
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:35,344 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [atlassian.config.xml.AbstractDom4jXmlConfigurationPersister] saveDocumentAtomically Unable to move C:\atlassian\tutorial-confluence-macro-demo\target\confluence\home\confluence.cfg.xml5736989692032523721tmp to C:\atlassian\tutorial-confluence-macro-demo\target\confluence\home\confluence.cfg.xml. Falling back to non-atomic overwrite.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2016-03-29 20:45:35,364 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] [confluence.upgrade.impl.DefaultUpgradeGate] waitForBooleanValue Waiting to find if plugin dependent upgrades are required. Maximum wait time will be 90 seconds.
```

I also tried putting the driver-jar file into the web-inf/lib directory, but as Atlassian described on this page

https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/working-with-the-pom/managing-dependencies

this is not working anymore.

The error above has the following message:

```
Unresolved constraint in bundle com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.tutorial-confluence-macro-demo-tests [238]: 
              Unable to resolve 238.0: missing requirement [238.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.api) 
  [caused by: Unable to resolve 149.0: missing requirement [149.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jna)].  
              This error usually occurs when your plugin imports a package from another bundle with a specific version constraint and either the bundle providing that package doesn't meet those version constraints, or there is no bundle available that provides the specified package. For more details on how to fix this, see https://developer.atlassian.com/x/mQAN
```

So I am not quite sure what this message means.

Maybe somebody can help me out here.

**UPDATE**

After removing the Import-Package tag from the pom.xml

```
                <Import-Package>
                   org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                   org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
                    org.postgresql.*;resolution:="optional",
                    *
                </Import-Package>
```

It works.

Thanks a lot 
Hauke

Comment: As I read the error, the import-package statement cannot find an other package which exports the specific package. So remove this staement and try with dependencies.
Please verify that your /target  and /bin directory is clean, before rebuilding (atlas-clean -> atlas-package -> atlas-install-plugin). To be sure I manually delete these directories before building and installing.

Comment: Well, after removing the whole <Import-Package> it works. Thanks!

Comment: Good! then mark the question as resolved and you're done :)